# I can't use if ( ifs == NULL) command in VS 2013

Tags: c++

When compiling this code:

```
std::ifstream ifs("somefile.txt");
if(ifs == NULL)
```

I get an error

> no operator matches these operands "=="

I got the same error in every project with VS 2013, but I didn't have any problem in VS 2010.

How to solve this?

Comment: ifstream ifs ("somefile.txt");

Comment: Why are you comparing an ifstream to NULL?

Comment: @BeqaBukhradze Why would you think that would work?

Comment: So it's never NULL. Try `if(!ifs.fail())` of `if(!ifs)` or `if(!ifs.eof())` depending what you want to check. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ and section about good/bad/fail methods

Comment: to find out if importing data is end 
I don't know how much information I have in file

Comment: ifs.eof() tells you that you have hit the end of file, as the name EOF suggests. Check the docs, really..

Comment: and also - please add that note about "how much information.." to your question, it's important point telling what you actually need

Comment: The idiomatic check is `if ( !ifs )`.  `if ( ifs == NULL )` is guaranteed to have the same effect in C++03, but this was mainly due to historical reasons (but also the absence of `explicit` on conversion operators).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'd say it's more idiomatic to say `if (std::ifstream ifs("somefile.txt")) {...use ifs... }`, but either works, unlike quetzalcoatl's `if (!ifs.eof())` which may return `true` on an empty file as the `eof` flag is only set when an input operation exhausts input.

Comment: @TonyD I've never seen anyone put the definition of the stream directly in the `if`.  No point in adding to the confusion.

Comment: @JamesKanze: who says *I'm* adding to the confusion, just because you happen not to have seen (or noticed) something? ;-P  Anyway, you had your say, I had mine, anyone wants to do a survey of some huge body of disparate C++ can work out actual percentages of use we have a meaningful conclusion (whether one or both are idiomatic and to what extent), otherwise we're done....

Comment: @TonyD Putting a definition in a condition definitely adds to the confusion, regardless of what it is.  And I've worked in a lot of different shops, over 20 years, and read a lot of different articles, and this is the first time I've seen anyone put the definition in an `if`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: as defining streams, pointers, loop control variables (ever seen `for (int i = ...`?) etc. as they're able to be initialised and localised to the scope of use lessens confusion IMHO, and I've similarly >20 years' professional experience, long involvement with comp.lang.c++, read my share of gotw and C++ literature, etc over the years, so we can only agree to disagree...

Comment: @TonyD A `for` is designed to have a definition (in its first part); it's expected.  For the rest, doing two things is a single statement is obfuscation, and wouldn't pass code review at any of the places I've worked.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `for` was included as an illustration of precedence for such *scoping*... recommending against such code would get you off any review or standards group I had influence with, we're not getting any new information here, so what exactly do you think your continued assertions are going to change here?

Comment: (`if (D* p = dynamic_cast<D*>(p_b)) ...` is another classic example of restricting scope, so a `nullptr` `p` can't be accidentally dereferenced later, the `p` identifier can be conveniently reused etc..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `std::basic_ios` (from which `std::basic_ifstream` inherits) changed in C++11. In particular, it's conversion operator `operator void*` changed to [`explicit operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), so what you're trying to do is no longer valid. Nonetheless, it was never a common way to check the state of your stream. Instead, just do `if (!ifs)`.

The C++ standard changes, now faster than ever, and MSVC has a habit of just mixing together the different standards until they fully support the latest one. You can expect some code to break when things change, although the committee aim to minimise this as much as possible.